# How to add Activity to manifest.xml in right way?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

should I write each activity in android manifest and how? Must each activity have intent-filter, or not?

Answer (score 44):

Multiple ways to add activites in Manifest file.

intent filter is not a necessary tag for all activites,it is optional.

Add Activity in application tag in your manifest:

```
 <!-- Main Activity-->
    <activity android:name=".YourActivityName" >
        <intent-filter>
      <!-- MAIN represents that it is the Main Activity-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <!-- Launcher Denotes that it will be the first launching activity-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <!--Add Other activities like this-->
    <activity android:name=".YourActivityName2" >
 <!--Default Intent Filter-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <!--OR Other activities like this And  intent filter is not necessary in other activites-->
    <activity android:name=".YourActivityName3" >
    </activity>
 <!--OR Add Other activities like this-->
    <activity android:name=".YourActivityName4" />
```

Comment: Hey cheers for this answer. I copied in     <activity android:name="YourActivityName2" > and it didn't work. But then copied in <activity android:name="YourActivityName3" >
    </activity> and it worked fine. I don't know if somethings changed or I was just doing it wrong. Just thought i'd let you know.

Comment: Does it require to add a '.'  before the activity name, <activity android:name=".YourActivityName3" > </activity> ?

Answer (score 9):

An activity must be mentioned inside an

```
<activity>
    ...
</activity>
```

tag. Each of the activity tags must be specified inside

```
<application>
    ...
</application>
```

tag.

The default activity needs to have a

```
<intent-filter>
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

tag which will make the android system understand that this activity will be called at the time of App Launch.

A  can contain several attributes however, only the name attribute is mandatory.

Following is the complete list: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Default Activity Tag:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Other Activity Tag:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectSubjectActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You must mention each activity in android manifest.

Not all activity need intent filter.
intent filters show when to launch this activity.
usually you will have one activity with intent filter that is to show that it is first activity when application is launched.

inside application tag in your manifest:

```
        <activity android:name="ActivtyName" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ActivtyName2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

only `android:name="ActivtyName"` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse ADT, when creating new Activity instead of creating a class create a Activity from New > Others... This way ADT automaticly adds your Activity to Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I realize "Android Developer Fundamentals Course". I see that there is a subtle difference when adding activities with nested elements and without them.

Default activity is defined this way:

```
<activity
    android:name=""
    android:label=""/>
```

When you add activity with closing tag (because there is nested element), you need move name attribute to opening tag:

```
<activity android:name="">
    android:label=""/>

    <meta-data/>

</activity>
```

On https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

we can find that name attribute is mandatory:

> The name of your subclass must be specified with the name attribute,
> using the full package designation.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write entry in manifest for every activity and No intent filter is not necessary. You can simply write this :

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.chatter.List"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: where should I use intent-filter?

Comment: when you said that this activity will work only for specific type of intents, so you filter them out.