# Chrome issues in Android 13

Tags: java, android

In Android 13 not open the chrome browser I can't open chrome using htm text

Error-unable to find explicit activity class{com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main} have you declared this activity in your Android Manifest.xml

I am trying to open chrome browser in Android 13
I want to open chrome browser using html text

Comment: As the error says, probably you need to add your activity in the manifest. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871106/16404907
By the way if you add your code, we'll help you better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.